# Which Image value need to add to Source field to upload FB photo

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to upload a photo to facebook via my laravel application. I have some questions.

I uploaded photo and the got image properties with dd($_FILES) and the result is

```
array:1 [
     "file" => array:5 [
     "name" => "shailene_woodley_divergent-wide.jpg"
     "type" => "image/jpeg"
     "tmp_name" => "/private/var/folders/b0/l7j5d8tj2ynflwt8srr5lywm0000gn/T/phpxHoc6s"
     "error" => 0
     "size" => 573957
     ]
 ]
```

and my controller is

```
try {
   $response = $this->fb->post('/me/photos',
    array(
        'source' => ?????????,
        'caption' => 'nothing',
        'published' => 'false'
      )
    );
```

Please let me know which value of photo do i need to add in source field.

thanks